# Highstock stochastic %d is not correct

Tags: highcharts

I am using the stochastic indicator with the 14, 3 day moving average. The resulting %k is correct, but the %d is not. For aapl on September 14, 2018, the stochastic fast is 58.95 and 56.3. However, the values returned by highstock is 44.8 and 56.3. The series it is linked to in my case is a candlestick chart. The data includes the time in milliseconds, the open, high, low and closing prices.

Are there any special parameters I need to set to get the correct %d? Thank you.

Comment: Please add your try and code.

Comment: Hello, Ashu. Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/4spyex5d/10/ Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your report. Unfortunately, you're definitely right. It's caused by the wrong start point of calculating values od `%d`. I've just reported it on our GitHub repository. Here is the link to issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8965

Until it will be fixed, you can apply a custom fix which overrides the `getValues` function. Here is the code:

```
(function(H) {
    var isArray = H.isArray,
    SMA = H.seriesTypes.sma,
    reduce = H.reduce,
    getArrayExtremes = function (arr, minIndex, maxIndex) {
        return reduce(arr, function (prev, target) {
            return [
                Math.min(prev[0], target[minIndex]),
                Math.max(prev[1], target[maxIndex])
            ];
        }, [Number.MAX_VALUE, -Number.MAX_VALUE]);
    };
  console.log(H.seriesTypes.stochastic.prototype)
    H.seriesTypes.stochastic.prototype.getValues = function(series, params) {
  var periodK = params.periods[0],
                periodD = params.periods[1],
                xVal = series.xData,
                yVal = series.yData,
                yValLen = yVal ? yVal.length : 0,
                SO = [], // 0- date, 1-%K, 2-%D
                xData = [],
                yData = [],
                slicedY,
                close = 3,
                low = 2,
                high = 1,
                CL, HL, LL, K,
                D = null,
                points,
                extremes,
                i;


            // Stochastic requires close value
            if (
                yValLen < periodK ||
                !isArray(yVal[0]) ||
                yVal[0].length !== 4
            ) {
                return false;
            }

            // For a N-period, we start from N-1 point, to calculate Nth point
            // That is why we later need to comprehend slice() elements list
            // with (+1)
            for (i = periodK - 1; i < yValLen; i++) {
                slicedY = yVal.slice(i - periodK + 1, i + 1);

                // Calculate %K
                extremes = getArrayExtremes(slicedY, low, high);
                LL = extremes[0]; // Lowest low in %K periods
                CL = yVal[i][close] - LL;
                HL = extremes[1] - LL;
                K = CL / HL * 100;

                xData.push(xVal[i]);
                yData.push([K, null]);

                // Calculate smoothed %D, which is SMA of %K
                if (i >= (periodK - 1) + (periodD - 1)) {
                    points = SMA.prototype.getValues.call(this, {
                        xData: xData.slice(-periodD),
                        yData: yData.slice(-periodD)
                    }, {
                        period: periodD
                    });
                    D = points.yData[0];
                }

                SO.push([xVal[i], K, D]);
                yData[yData.length - 1][1] = D;
            }

            return {
                values: SO,
                xData: xData,
                yData: yData
            };
  }
})(Highcharts)
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/d4hjmze1/

Comment: That did it. Thank you for your quick response.