# Stochastic on a weekly basis

Tags: highcharts

Looking to setup a stochastic on a weekly basis but the chart is on daily data.

Tried using grouping, which at first seems to work, but it does not include the current week, it needs a full week to complete it.  If the grouping was reversed, where it started on the current day and worked its way back x days, that would work.

So in the end, need the following: **H** = Max high of past 7 days, **L** = MIN low of past 7 days, **C** = Close of 7th day, **O** = Open of day 1

I can generate this data and store in DB if too slow to generate on the fly, but how would I link a separate dataset to a stochastic?

[Highstock stochastic %d is not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341625/highstock-stochastic-d-is-not-correct) seems promising where the K and D are calculated on the fly.

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the indicator using available [API options](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.stochastic.params) related to the indicator parameters.

If this doesn't help there might be two options.

1. It's a bug in the implementation and should be [reported](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues) or an enhancement is required and it could be reported in the same place or using the Highcharts [UserVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general). Regardless of place, please check first is the same issue is not yet reported.
2. It's not the indicator type that you were looking for, so you could a custom one on your own using [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/custom-technical-indicators).